# Angular2 with combineAll from rxjs

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to use the combineAll from the observable function but i keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: unknown type returned
at Object.subscribeToResult (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:35082:27)
at CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/main.bundle.js:39140:46)
at CombineLatestSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32309:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:34474:30)
at InnerSubscriber._complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:31646:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32309:18)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32327:26)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32309:18)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32327:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:32309:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:21511:38)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://164.132.97.206:10000/polyfills.bundle.js:18029:35)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://164.132.97.206:10000/vendor.bundle.js:15519:37)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://164.132.97.206:10000/polyfills.bundle.js:18028:40)
at Zone.runTask (http://164.132.97.206:10000/polyfills.bundle.js:17918:47)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://164.132.97.206:10000/polyfills.bundle.js:18099:33)
```

Here is the part of the code i'm using somehow

```
export interface VertexOperation {
  action: string,//add, erase, update
  mainVertex?: string,
  mainKey?: string,
  vertexName: string,
  edgeName: string,
  vertex: any,
  edge: any
}
public updateVertexEdge(operation:VertexOperation): Observable<QueryVertexConnection> {
    return this._http.post(this._userService.apiEndPoint+'updateLink/'+operation.vertexName, operation, {headers: this._userService.getHeaders()})
        .map(
            (response:Response) => {
                let res = response.json();
                console.log(res);
                return (res);
            })
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().message || 'ServerErr'));
}
public updateEdges(items: Array<VertexOperation>) {
    console.log(items);
    return Observable.from(items).concatMap(
        (val) => {
            return this.updateVertexEdge(val);
        }
    ).combineAll();
}
this.updateEdges(vertexEdges).subscribe(
      (evResult) => {
        console.log(evResult);
      },
      (errEv) => {
        console.log(errEv);
      }
    );
```

The call to the api endpoint don't have any problem and the update is done but i keep getting this error, i'm not sure if i'm not using the combineAll correctly, i've read some post on stackoverflow where it was used like that so i'm not really sure what is wrong in this.
If anyone had some similar issues or had some better way of combining some request i'd be really thankful if you could share your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `map` instead of `concatMap`.

The error showed that `combineAll` receive incorrect type. `combineAll` expect `Observable of Observables`, while `concatMap` return an `Observable`

Something like this :

```
public updateEdges(items: Array<VertexOperation>) {
    console.log(items);
    return Observable.from(items).map(
        (val) => {
            return this.updateVertexEdge(val);
        }
    ).combineAll();
}
```